# bundle nokogiri

Tags: ruby, bundler, nokogiri

I'm setting up a new machine running Mac OS 10.8 and Ruby 1.9.3 through rbenv.

After many tentative starts, and reading many Stack Overflow answers, I was able to install Nokogiri using:

```
sudo gem install nokogiri -- --with-xml2-include=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.8.0/include/libxml2 --with-xml2-lib=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.8.0/lib --with-xslt-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/libxslt/1.1.28 --with-iconv-include=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.13.1/include --with-iconv-lib=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.13.1/lib
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed nokogiri-1.5.6
1 gem installed
```

Now I'm trying to bundle up a Rails application but I can't install Nokogiri. I always get the error that libxml2 is missing.

The last command I tried is:

```
bundle config build.nokogiri -- --with-xml2-include=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.8.0/include/libxml2 --with-xml2-lib=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.8.0/lib --with-xslt-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/libxslt/1.1.28 --with-iconv-include=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.13.1/include --with-iconv-lib=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.13.1/lib
bundle install
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [the updated installation instructions for Homebrew](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html)? FWIW, I've never had a problem with MacPorts

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need the -- in your config command. See the [bundle config](http://bundler.io/v1.6/bundle_config.html) page. I know this question is old, but maybe someone else can benefit.

```
bundle config build.nokogiri --with-xml2-include=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.8.0/include/libxml2 --with-xml2-lib=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.8.0/lib --with-xslt-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/libxslt/1.1.28 --with-iconv-include=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.13.1/include --with-iconv-lib=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.13.1/lib
bundle install
```

You can check your ~/.bundle/config file to see if the configuration was properly recorded.

I also just submitted this [bug](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/3053) to bundler. See it if you get a `Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string` while building.